# Does Karana Sahareera belong to Sookshma Shareera or Karana Shareera?

Tags: vedas, vedanta, advaita, adi-shankaracharya

I thought that Anandamaya Kosha belongs to Karana  Shareera, infact I thought Anandamaya Shareera itself is Karana Shareera because it is said in [Tattva Bodha](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://www.v0.chinfo.org/images/userupload/Reflections/02_Tattva_Bodha.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwjt5eeNgYnzAhUczjgGHV9LAmEQFnoECAUQAQ&usg=AOvVaw0ujNOwNdCojSF-7BC0HAyD), which is traditionally considered a work of Adi Shankaracharya.

[image]

But I recently saw [this video](https://youtu.be/9171s3hPVhQ?t=626s) where a Guruji belonging to Advaita tradition says that Anandamaya Kosha belongs to Sookshma Shareera. The video is in Kannada, but the rough translation is

> Anandamaya Kosha along with three other  Koshas of Pranamaya, Manomaya
> and Vijnanamaya Koshas constitute Sookshma Shareera with 19 parts, 5
> Jnanendriyas, 5  Karmendriyas, 5 Pranas, 4 Antahkaranas.

So now I'm confused, can any one please give references from authentic work of Shri Adi Shankaracharya (preferably from his Prasthana Traya Bhashya) which clarifies as to which Shareera does Anandamaya Kosha belong to?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129875/discussion-on-question-by-mr-green-gold-does-karana-sahareera-belong-to-sookshma).

Comment: Do you consider Vivekachdamani as an authentic work of Shankara? (I dont). If yes, in Vivekachudamani both karana sarira and Anandamaya kosa are considered to be related to sushupti - sort of an indirect equation.

Comment: @zero ohh yeah I don't think Vivekachudamani was Adi Shankaracharya's work as it is said disagree with his Brahma Sutra Bhashya, if that's true. Do you know the verse of Viveka Chudamani which says this. How can it disagree with Vidyaranya?

Comment: Vivekachudamani does not disagree with Vidyaranya. Latter makes the equation explicit, former makes it implicit. Check verses 120 and 208. Here - https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/vivekachudamani

Comment: @zero thanks, I saw it, but there's nothing there which says Anandamaya kosha belings Sookshma shareera as far as I can understand. It's only saying in Sushpti one experiences Ananda of Anandamaya Kosha.

Comment: Verse 120 mentions karana sarira as associated with deep sleep. Verse 208 mentions Anandamaya kosa as associated with deep sleep. IMO, its an indirect equation. If you think otherwise, its ok. For the record, I personally think deep sleep is not Anandamaya kosa, but is Ananda or brahman itself, and the link between karana sarira and Anandamaya kosa is of no personal interest to me.

Comment: @zero yes that's correct so Vivekachudamani agrees with Panchadashi. Ok I misunderstood it. So even Vivekachudamani says the same thing, that Anandamaya Kosha is Karana Sharira. Ok great.

Comment: @zero deep sleep is not Brahman itself imho because then it would cause realization, because whoever experiences Brahman will be realozed and liberated. That's not the case with sleep. People are still in Ajnana, and as lomg as they are in Ajnana they cannot experience pure Brahman. But it's one of the closest thing the non realized can experience Brahman. Also do you have any verses to support your position??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129944/discussion-between-mr-green-gold-and-zero).